# Color BMP image converted with mean filter results in skewing while others are successful

Tags: c, image, mean

Excuse me, I'm working on my computer course assignment, which is about image filtering with mean filter. It is required not to use external libraries of C++ and C language, but now it has encountered some errors. I am processing a color BMP image with a width of 322 and a height of 315. As can be seen in the following image, the converted image is skewed, while there is no error in converting other images, and they are successfully converted. However, when I use Python to convert the image below, it can be converted normally.

[image]

[image]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define getLineBytes(biWidth, biBitCount) (biWidth * biBitCount / 8 + 3) / 4 * 4;
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    unsigned char bfType[2];
    unsigned long bfSize;
    unsigned short bfReserved1;
    unsigned short bfReserved2;
    unsigned long bfOffBits;
} fileHeader;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
    unsigned long biSize;
    long biWidth;
    long biHeight;
    unsigned short biPlanes;
    unsigned short biBitCount;
    unsigned long biCompression;
    unsigned long biSizeImage;
    long biXPixPerMeter;
    long biYPixPerMeter;
    unsigned long biClrUsed;
    unsigned long biClrImportant;
} fileInfo;

typedef struct tagRGBQUAD {
    unsigned char rgbBlue;
    unsigned char rgbGreen;
    unsigned char rgbRed;
    unsigned char rgbReserved;
} rgbq;

void readBMP(FILE *fpBMP, fileHeader *fh, fileInfo *fi, rgbq *fq) {
    fread(fh, sizeof(fileHeader), 1, fpBMP);
    fread(fi, sizeof(fileInfo), 1, fpBMP);
    long oldBiWidth = getLineBytes(fi->biWidth, fi->biBitCount);
    fi->biBitCount = 8;
    long newBiWidth = getLineBytes(fi->biWidth, fi->biBitCount);
    fi->biSizeImage = newBiWidth * fi->biHeight;
    fh->bfOffBits = sizeof(fileHeader) + sizeof(fileInfo) + 256 * sizeof(rgbq);
    fh->bfSize = fh->bfOffBits + fi->biSizeImage;
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        fq[i].rgbBlue = fq[i].rgbGreen = fq[i].rgbRed = i;
    }
}

void writeBMP(FILE *fpGray, fileHeader *fh, fileInfo *fi, rgbq *fq) {
    fwrite(fh, sizeof(fileHeader), 1, fpGray);
    fwrite(fi, sizeof(fileInfo), 1, fpGray);
    fwrite(fq, sizeof(rgbq), 256, fpGray);
}

void convertToGray(FILE *fpBMP, FILE *fpGray, fileInfo *fi) {
    unsigned char rgbImgData[3];
    unsigned int grayImgData;
    unsigned char rgbAnthor;
    long oldBiWidth = getLineBytes(fi->biWidth, fi->biBitCount);
    long newBiWidth = getLineBytes(fi->biWidth, 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < fi->biHeight; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newBiWidth; j++) {
            if (j < fi->biWidth)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                    fread(&rgbImgData[k], 1, 1, fpBMP);
                }
                grayImgData = (int)((float)rgbImgData[0] * 0.299 + (float)rgbImgData[1] * 0.587 + (float)rgbImgData[2] * 0.114);
            }
            else {
                grayImgData = 0;
            }
            fwrite(&grayImgData,1, 1, fpGray);
        }
        for (int k = fi->biWidth * 3; k < oldBiWidth; k++) {
            fread(&rgbAnthor, 1, 1, fpBMP);
        }
    }   
}

int main() {
    unsigned char bmpRGBPath[] = "test.bmp";
    unsigned char bmpGrayPath[] = "gray.bmp";
    FILE *fpBMP, *fpGray;
    fileHeader fh;
    fileInfo fi;
    rgbq fq[256];
    fpBMP = fopen(bmpRGBPath, "rb");
    fpGray = fopen(bmpGrayPath, "wb");
    readBMP(fpBMP, &fh, &fi, fq);
    writeBMP(fpGray, &fh, &fi, fq);
    convertToGray(fpBMP, fpGray, &fi);
    fclose(fpGray);
    fclose(fpBMP);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not padding each line to a multiple of 4 bytes when writing the data. Other images might work if their size naturally pads to 4 bytes.

Comment: and then you should either read or skip past the padding.

Comment: You are right, I don't seem to have skipped any bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues ...

1. In a `.bmp` file, raster lines must be aligned to a multiple of 4.
2. You're *not* accounting for the padding at the end of each row.
3. Doing `fread/fwrite` a single pixel at a time is *slow*.
4. Faster and *easier* to do the I/O on whole rows.
5. Unless you're compiling for 32 bit mode, using `long` in the structs is incorrect.

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated.

By reading/writing a row at a time (i.e. the row *stride*), it accounts for the padding *without* seeking the file.

```
// gfxdemo/bmporig.c -- BMP to grayscale demo

#include <stdio.h>

//#define MPACKED           __attribute__((packed))
#define MPACKED         /**/

#if DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

#define xfread(_xf,_ptr,_len) \
    fread(_ptr,1,_len,_xf)
#define xfwrite(_xf,_ptr,_len) \
    fwrite(_ptr,1,_len,_xf)

// winX compatible types
typedef unsigned char BYTE, *PBYTE, *LPBYTE;
typedef short SHORT, *PSHORT, *LPSHORT;
typedef unsigned short WORD, *PWORD, *LPWORD;
typedef int LONG, *PLONG, *LPLONG;
typedef unsigned int ULONG, *PULONG, *LPULONG;
typedef unsigned int DWORD, *PDWORD, *LPDWORD;

#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    BYTE bfType[2];
    DWORD bfSize;
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2;
    DWORD bfOffBits;
} MPACKED fileHeader;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
    DWORD biSize;
    LONG biWidth;
    LONG biHeight;
    WORD biPlanes;
    WORD biBitCount;
    DWORD biCompression;
    DWORD biSizeImage;
    LONG biXPixPerMeter;
    LONG biYPixPerMeter;
    DWORD biClrUsed;
    DWORD biClrImportant;
} MPACKED fileInfo;

typedef struct tagRGBQUAD {
    BYTE rgbBlue;
    BYTE rgbGreen;
    BYTE rgbRed;
    BYTE rgbReserved;
} MPACKED rgbq;

#define BMPOFF_HDR      0
#define BMPOFF_INFO     (BMPOFF_HDR + sizeof(fileHeader))
#define BMPOFF_CMAP     (BMPOFF_INFO + sizeof(fileInfo))
#define BMPOFF_DATA     (BMPOFF_CMAP + (sizeof(rgbq) * 256))

// bmp_line_bytes -- get number of bytes in line (i.e. the stride)
int
bmp_line_bytes(int biWidth, int biBitCount)
{

    return (biWidth * biBitCount / 8 + 3) / 4 * 4;
}

// readBMP -- read in BMP header/info/cmap
void
readBMP(FILE *fpBMP, fileHeader *fh, fileInfo *fi, rgbq *fq)
{

    xfread(fpBMP, fh, sizeof(*fh));
    xfread(fpBMP, fi, sizeof(*fi));
    xfread(fpBMP, fq, sizeof(*fq) * 256);
}

// writeBMP -- write out BMP header/info/cmap
void
writeBMP(FILE *fpGray, fileHeader *fh, fileInfo *fi, rgbq *fq)
{
    xfwrite(fpGray, fh, sizeof(*fh));
    xfwrite(fpGray, fi, sizeof(*fi));
    xfwrite(fpGray, fq, sizeof(*fq) * 256);
}

void
convertToGray(FILE *fpBMP, FILE *fpGray, fileHeader *fh, fileInfo *fi, rgbq *fq)
{
    unsigned int grayImgData;

    readBMP(fpBMP, fh, fi, fq);

    dbgprt("convertToGray: biWidth=%d biBitCount=%d\n",
        fi->biWidth,fi->biBitCount);

    // get stride of input file
    int oldBiWidth = bmp_line_bytes(fi->biWidth,fi->biBitCount);
    dbgprt("convertToGray: oldBiWidth=%d\n",oldBiWidth);
    BYTE oldbuf[oldBiWidth];

    // get stride of output file
    fi->biBitCount = 8;
    int newBiWidth = bmp_line_bytes(fi->biWidth, fi->biBitCount);
    dbgprt("convertToGray: newBiWidth=%d\n",newBiWidth);
    BYTE newbuf[newBiWidth];

    fi->biSizeImage = newBiWidth * fi->biHeight;
    fh->bfOffBits = sizeof(fileHeader) + sizeof(fileInfo) + 256 * sizeof(rgbq);
    fh->bfSize = fh->bfOffBits + fi->biSizeImage;

    // convert colormap to grayscale
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        fq[i].rgbBlue = fq[i].rgbGreen = fq[i].rgbRed = i;

    // output new headers
    writeBMP(fpGray, fh, fi, fq);

    // position streams to place for pixel data
    fseek(fpBMP, BMPOFF_DATA, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(fpGray, BMPOFF_DATA, SEEK_SET);

    for (int i = 0;  i < fi->biHeight;  i++) {
        // read in current input row
        //fseek(fpBMP, BMPOFF_DATA + (i * oldBiWidth), SEEK_SET);
        xfread(fpBMP, oldbuf, sizeof(oldbuf));

        // create output row
        BYTE *old = oldbuf;
        for (int j = 0;  j < newBiWidth;  j++, old += 3) {
            if (j < fi->biWidth) {
                grayImgData = (int) ((float) old[0] * 0.299 +
                    (float) old[1] * 0.587 +
                    (float) old[2] * 0.114);
            }
            else
                grayImgData = 0;

            newbuf[j] = grayImgData;
        }

        // write out output row
        //fseek(fpGray, BMPOFF_DATA + (i * newBiWidth), SEEK_SET);
        xfwrite(fpGray, newbuf, sizeof(newbuf));
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    const char *bmpRGBPath = "inp.bmp";
    const char *bmpGrayPath = "out.bmp";

    FILE *fpBMP;
    FILE *fpGray;

    fileHeader fh;
    fileInfo fi;
    rgbq fq[256];

    fpBMP = fopen(bmpRGBPath, "rb");
    fpGray = fopen(bmpGrayPath, "wb");

    convertToGray(fpBMP, fpGray, &fh, &fi, fq);

    fclose(fpGray);
    fclose(fpBMP);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction! I think my problem should have been resolved now.